# ASP.Net MVC Javascript Keyboard not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

My virtual keyboard was working but when I added the button inside a Form instead of a Div it stopped working.

**This is my javascript code:**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        function input(e) {
            //var u = document.rateformular;// duplicated with f and not used
            var f = document.rateformular;
            var b = f.elements["ratezeichen"];
            var zeichen = b.value;
            zeichen.value = zeichen.value + e.value



        }
```

**And the button has this onclick:**

```
<div class="cities">
       <input id="btn1" type="button" value="a"  class="btn btn-default" onclick="input(this);" />
   </div>
```

Comment: move the function `input` outside document-ready handler. The function should be in global scope to be used as inline event handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your input function has to be declared in the global scope

- outside `$(document).ready(function () {...`

or

- directly attached to global object `window.input = function(e) { ...`

Comment: `onclick="input(this);"` will work just fine, problem is that its not defined in global scope

Comment: first arg of event handler should be event object, not dom element. using e.target or this keyword is way better

Comment: _first arg of event handler should be event object, not dom element_ not correct. Its _true_ when using jquery event binding or vanilla js `addEventListener` method

Comment: the e value is coming as undefined

Comment: @PauloMartins, stick to `onclick="input(this);"`

Comment: @PauloMartins seems to be my mistake, it's only a scope error

Comment: @Satpal well you are right, and I was wrong. Not used to inline event handling anymore :(

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to fix my problem.

```
function input(e) {

        var f = document.rateformular;
        var b = f.elements["ratezeichen"];
        if (b.value == 0) {
            b.value = b.value + e.value;
        }
        else {



        }
```

The main problem was in the scope and then I had to make a few changes in the code.
Thanks StackOverFlow.

The if cicle is to prevent that the user can input 2 letters, they only can type 1 letter, it's the max lenght of the TextBox, it's part of my application.